# Как организовать разработку приложения

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать разработку веб-приложения, а именно, как организовать взаимосвязь между применяемыми технологиями.

Я хочу создать веб-приложение по обмену вещами между пользователями. Приложение пишется на **Java** + **Spring MVC** + **Spring Security** (для авторизации пользователя) + **Hibernate** с использованием сборщика **Maven**, а в качестве СУБД используется **HSQLDB**. Для Представления используется **JSP**. Сервер приложений - встроенный **Jetty**, не требующий внешнего веб-контейнера.

#### Вопросы:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы проект автоматически собирался и работал на любом ПК с предустановленными JDK и Maven? Что для этого нужно сделать?
2. Что сделать, чтобы нужная схема данных автоматически создавалась и заполнялась начальными данными при первом запуске веб-приложения?
   Это должно происходить именно при первом запуске приложения, а не при каждом его включении.
3. Расскажите поподробнее про то, как мне организовать доступ к HSQLDB из Hibernate, учитывая требования (1 и 2) и как хранить/упаковать БД и СУБД исходя из этого.
4. Требуется также написать скрипт сборки проекта с помощью Maven и показать его исходники заказчику. Что в данной ситуации будет скриптом сборки? Maven ведь декларативный сборщик.

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: [Смотрите в сторону Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) Все перечисленное там практически из коробки. Попробуйте собрать тестовый проект.

Comment: Мало похоже на ответ. Можно подробнее по каждому пункту?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Для этого достаточно использовать maven в качестве билд-системы. Тогда на любой машине с установленными maven и jdk можно будет выполнить

   ```
   mvn package
   ```

   и получить артефакт (вероятнее всего вы захотите zip-архив) с вашим продуктом. Вам скорее всего понадобятся [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) и/или [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).
2. Автоматическое создание схемы можно доверить Hibernate (используя параметр `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`), но *предпочтительнее* делать это SQL-скриптом. Если планируются апдейты приложения и схемы данных, стоит задуматься об использовании средств версионирования схемы БД. Например, [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) умеет проверять при старте версию схемы в БД последовательно накатывать необходимые миграции (SQL-скрипты, обновляющие схему) на БД и заливать исходные данные из XML.
3. Файл данных БД можно хранить в директории приложения или за её пределами, например, в `$HOME/.myapplication/` или в `/var` в Linux (`%APPDATA%/myapplication` в случае Windows). Хранение базы данных в отдельной рабочей директории даст ей больше шансов на выживание при удалении и переустановке вашей программы.
4. Мавеновский `pom.xml` и будет скриптом сборки. Декларативным скриптом.

---

Примерно все это можно получить "из коробки", используя Spring Boot. Просто идете на страницу http://start.spring.io, жмете <kbd>Switch to the full version</kbd>? заполняете форму и отмечаете флажками пункты:

- Web
- Security
- JPA
- HSQLDB

и <kbd>Generate project</kbd> в конце.

На выходе у вас будет архив с готовым скелетом приложения c maven-скриптом как раз под ваши нужды. Нужно будет доработать напильником: заменить Tomcat на Jetty и досыпать в зависимости Flyway, например.

Comment: По второму пункту - если я использую такой параметр в Hibernate hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update то структура БД будет создаваться только при первом запуске приложения после установки или при каждом старте? 
И почему предпочтительнее использовать запросы? И как это сделать для поставленной задачи? Куда эти запросы прописать, чтобы структура и данные генерировались только при первом старте?

Comment: Режим `update` - обновляет схему БД до известной hibernate-у. Первый раз схема будет пустая, и он ее накатит. Очищать в конкретно этом режиме при рестартах он ее не будет. Запросы предпочтительнее, потому что вы лучше контролируете, что  создаете в БД с учетом особенностей конкретной СУБД.

Comment: Как сделать? Написать руками или сгенерировать текст с существующей базы. В самом тексте DDL-запросов можно проверить существование таблиц перед созданием. Запросы положить в файлы и паковать с приложением. При старте проверять существование нужных таблиц и выполнять скрипт, если их нет. Все это умеет автоматически делать Flyway.

Comment: Спасибо! Еще был бы очень благодарен если бы вы поделились ссылочкой по поводу работы с DDL запросами в hibernate, чтобы удобно было вручную настроить работу по созданию Схемы БД и заполнение данными

Comment: Для выполнения SQL-скриптов можно использовать [`doWork`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work)) как в этом вопросе: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220846/execute-ddl-from-hibernate

Comment: ОК! Спасибо - попробуем!

Comment: Можно еще вопросик? Я только щас заметил, но я наверное неправильно выразился в пункте 1.  Я имею ввиду, что мое приложение можно было бы установить и запустить на любом ПК с предустановленными Java и Maven. Каким будет конечный файл? Какого расширения? И как человек его запустить и установит?

Comment: Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, в каком режиме у меня должна работать БД и в какую папку  ее положить? Должна ли она работать как удаленная Бд или локальная (In Process Mode)?

Comment: @Nosafe Я уже сделал очень многое в своем приложении остался как раз пункт по тому вопросу, куда поместить БД чтобы веб-приложение могло с ней работать. Мой Hibernate не может получить доступ к данным и постоянно выдает UserLacksPrivilege or object not found "User".